# Bash Script - Python can't find a path

Tags: python, bash, ycsb

Please I need help!

This is my first bash script, and it's calling a python script at some points.
But I always get this output at line 28 and 40:

```
./startTests.sh: line 28: 'logs/tp1/load-test1-workloada.txt': No such file or directory
```

The directory logs/tp1 **do exist**!
I think it's something with the char '>' that I have to use there, but I don't know how to fix it.

This is my script:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -e "\033[01;34m------------------------------"
echo -e "|      Testes YCSB 0.17      |"
echo -e "------------------------------\033[01;37m"

echo -e 'Está rodando o script da raiz do YCSB? (y/n)'
read yesno

if [ $yesno = 'y' ]; then
    echo -e 'Número de throughputs:'
    read numOfThroughputs

    echo -e 'Número de testes:'
    read numOfTests

    echo -e 'Iniciando...'

    for ((throughput = 1; throughput <= $numOfThroughputs; throughput++)); do
        echo -e '\033[01;32m------------------------------'
        echo -e "Throughput  $throughput "
        echo -e '------------------------------\033[01;37m'
        for ((test = 1; test <= $numOfTests; test++)); do
            echo -e '\033[01;32m------------------------------'
            echo -e "Iciando teste $test"
            echo -e '------------------------------\033[01;37m'
            echo -e 'Loading Workload A'
            python  ./bin/ycsb load mongodb-async -P workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb://172.18.0.3:27017/ycsb?w=1 -P config/load.dat -s > "'logs/tp${throughput}/load-test${test}-workloada.txt'"

            for workload in {a,b,c,,f,d,e}; do
                if [ $workload = 'e' ]; then
                    echo -e "\033[01;33mPreparação para workload $workload"
                    echo -e "Apague o banco e precione QUALQUER TECLA 2X"
                    read enter
                    echo -e "Precione QUALQUER TECLA\033[01;37m"
                    read enter2
                    python  ./bin/ycsb load mongodb-async -P workloads/workloade -p mongodb.url=mongodb://172.18.0.3:27017/ycsb?w=1 -P config/load.dat -s > "'logs/tp${throughput}/load-test${test}-workloade.txt'"
                fi
                echo -e "Workload $workload"
                python  ./bin/ycsb run mongodb-async -P workloads/workload"${workload}" -p mongodb.url=mongodb://172.18.0.3:27017/ycsb?w=1 -P config/runtp"${throughput}".dat -s > ""'logs/tp${throughput}/run-test${test}-workload${workload}.txt'"
            done
            echo -e "\033[01;32mTeste $test finalizado!"
            echo -e "\033[01;33mApague o banco e precione QUALQUER TECLA 2X"
            read enter
            echo -e "Precione QUALQUER TECLA\033[01;37m"
            read enter2
        done
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ogs/tp1 may be there but this is not same as 'logs/tp1/'.
You should remove the single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the single quotes inside double quotes.

```
> "'logs/tp${throughput}/load-test${test}-workloada.txt'"
```

is putting literal single quotes in the pathname, since single quotes have no special meaning inside double quotes. That should be

```
> "logs/tp${throughput}/load-test${test}-workloada.txt"
```

You also have this on a later line:

```
> ""'logs/tp${throughput}/run-test${test}-workload${workload}.txt'"
```

This has an extra `"` at the beginning, which makes the quotes unbalanced. It should be:

```
> "logs/tp${throughput}/run-test${test}-workload${workload}.txt"
```